# Regex: Separate a string of characters with a non-consistent pattern (Oracle) (POSIX ERE)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

EDIT: This question pertains to Oracle implementation of regex (POSIX ERE) which does not support 'lookaheads'

I need to separate a string of characters with a comma, however, the pattern is not consistent and I am not sure if this can be accomplished with Regex.

Corpus: `1710ABCD.131711ABCD.431711ABCD.41711ABCD.4041711ABCD.25`

The pattern is basically 4 digits, followed by 4 characters, followed by a dot, followed by 1,2, or 3 digits!  To make the string above clear, this is how it looks like separated by a space `1710ABCD.13 1711ABCD.43 1711ABCD.4 1711ABCD.404 1711ABCD.25`

So the output of a replace operation should look like this:

```
1710ABCD.13,1711ABCD.43,1711ABCD.4,1711ABCD.404,1711ABCD.25
```

I was able to match the pattern using this regex:

```
(\d{4}\w{4}\.\d{1,3})
```

It does insert a comma but after the third digit beyond the dot (wrong, should have been after the second digit), but I cannot get it to do it in the right position and globally.

Here is a link to a fiddle
https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/329

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @CertainPerformance's answer, if you want to be able to match the last token, you can use an alternative match of `$`:

```
(\d{4}\w{4}\.\d{1,3})(?=\d{4}|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/331

EDIT: Since you now mentioned in the comment that you're using Oracle's implementation, you can simply do:

```
regexp_replace(corpus, '(\d{1,3})(\d{4})', '\1,\2')
```

to get your desired output:

```
1710ABCD.13,1711ABCD.43,1711ABCD.4,1711ABCD.404,1711ABCD.25
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/333

Comment: Works well, however, it looks like Oracle's implementation (POSIX ERE) does not support lookahead. Any suggestions on doing the same without lookahead?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for Oracle's implementation.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I also updated the question to make it clear that this was the intended platform.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I had to change the `$` in your answer to a backslash.  So it should be `regexp_replace(corpus, '(\d{1,3})(\d{4})', '\1,\2')`  Can you please update your answer?

Comment: Ah indeed. I forgot that Oracle uses backslash for backreference. Updated as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is a lookahead at the end of the regular expression, so that the greedy `\d{1,3}` backtracks until it's followed by 4 digits (indicating the start of the next substring):

```
(\d{4}\w{4}\.\d{1,3})(?=\d{4})
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/330

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue finding matches after the first one you must use the [`g`lobal flag `/g`](http://2ality.com/2013/08/regexp-g.html). The pattern is very tricky but it's feasible if you reverse the string.

### Demo

```js
var str = `1710ABCD.131711ABCD.431711ABCD.41711ABCD.4041711ABCD.25`;

// Reverse String
var rts = str.split("").reverse().join("");

// Do a reverse version of RegEx
/*In order to continue searching after the first match,
use the `g`lobal flag*/
var rgx = /(\d{1,3}\.\w{4}\d{4})/g;

// Replace on reversed String with a reversed substitution
var res = rts.replace(rgx, ` ,$1`);

// Revert the result back to normal direction 
var ser = res.split("").reverse().join("");

console.log(ser);
```